# Equality in cardinality of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a $n-$dimensional vector space over a finite field. Prove that the number of m-dimensional subspaces of $V$ equals $n-m$ dimensional subspaces.

I was thinking like this if $R$ be a $m$ dim subspace then $R^{\circ}$ is its annihilator of $(n-m)$ dim. We can think of the one-to-one map from set of m-dim subspaces to the set of their annihilators, then one-to-one map from the (n-m) dim. subspaces in $V'$ to their annihilators i.e. in $V''$. Since their is a natural isomorphism thus we can say that # n dim subspaces = # (n-m) dim subspaces. Please help me with my arguments. Correct wherever necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

=== For $\;j,k<r\;,\;\;j,k,r\in\Bbb N\;$ , we have that

$$j+k=n\implies \binom nj=\binom nk$$

=== How many linearly independent subsets of $\,V\,,\,\,|V|=p^n\;$ , are there with $\;m<p^n\;$ elements? How many with $\;p^n-m\;$ ?

=== Hint for the last hint: if $\,x\in V\;$ , then $\,\alpha x\;,\;\forall\;\alpha\in \Bbb F=$ our finite field, is linearly *dependent* on $\,x\;$, and thus once we choose a vector there are $\,|V|-|F|\;$ which are linearly *independent* from it...